# JavaScript: 2-D Array in a game

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to make a two dimensional array for a zork like game, using javascript, that will change the location of the player based on what they input. The HTML just contains a picture and a textarea. Here's what I got so far:

```
var currentLocale = "Earth";

     function updateDisplay() {
        var msg = "";
        switch (currentLocale) {
           case "Earth":  msg = "Your home...Earth.";
                           break;
           case "Mercury":  msg = "On Mercury";
                           break;
           case "Mars": msg = "On Mars";
                           break;
           default      : msg = "currentLocal matches no cases";
        }

        var taPtr = document.getElementById("taDisplay");
        var history = taPtr.value;
        taPtr.value = msg + "\n" + history; 
     }

     var navArr = [[1,2],[1,-1],[1,-1],[1,-1],
                   [2,3],[2,1],[2,-1],[2,-1],
                   [3,-1],[3,2],[3,-1],[3,-1]];
```

Where the second item in each sub array corresponds to a direction (1, north; 2, south; 3,east; 4, west; -1, can't go that way)and the first item represents the planet (1, earth; 2, mercury; 3, mars). Is there a way I can link that with the first function here?

Comment: I'd recommend redesigning it so that each planet is an object with the 'exits' from that planet as an array within that object.

Comment: I strongly suggest you to study OOP. Once learnt well, it will make your life extremely easier.